# Java DESERIALIZE a string and store it in a model

Tags: java, mysql, json, string, parsing

The below data is getting stored in my mysql table as LONGTEXT. I have to read and map it to my Java beans. Is there anyway to directly map this to a model?

```
    a:5:
    {s:5:"width";i:1368;s:6:"height";i:1026;s:4:"file";s:20:"2017/06/RED-
    CARD.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:10:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:20:"RED-
    CARD-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:20:"RED-CARD-
    300x225.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:225;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"medium_large";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:20:"RED-
    CARD-768x576.jpg";s:5:"width";i:768;s:6:"height";i:576;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:5:"large";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:21:"RED-CARD-
    1024x768.jpg";s:5:"width";i:1024;s:6:"height";i:768;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"post-thumbnail";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:21:"RED-CARD-
    1000x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:1000;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"mvp-post-thumb";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:21:"RED-CARD-
    1000x600.jpg";s:5:"width";i:1000;s:6:"height";i:600;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:16:"mvp-medium-thumb";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:20:"RED-CARD-
    450x270.jpg";s:5:"width";i:450;s:6:"height";i:270;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:13:"mvp-mid-thumb";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:20:"RED-
    CARD-300x180.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:180;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:15:"mvp-small-thumb";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:18:"RED-CARD-
    80x80.jpg";s:5:"width";i:80;s:6:"height";i:80;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:20:"sow-carousel-default";a:4:
    {s:4:"file";s:20:"RED-CARD-
    272x182.jpg";s:5:"width";i:272;s:6:"height";i:182;s:9:"mime-
    type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:
    {s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";
    s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";
    s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";
    s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";
    s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

I have a text like the above in my mysql table. I have to parse it and want to store it in my java model. Could someone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: what have you tried, and what problems are you facing?

Comment: This data is stored by some other programs. I am just trying to get RED-CARD-80x80.jpg from the above string. Is it a standard format something we can directly map to models?

Comment: that looks like a serialized php object. maybe have a look at this  https://github.com/kayahr/pherialize/